# img tag throwing off line-height

Tags: html, image, css

Alright, so this is some of the css and html:

css:

```
div {
    height:24px;
    line-height:24px;
}
```

html:

```
<div><img src="image.png"/>Text</div>
```

Now what that should (I think) produce is a div that is 24 pixels high, and the text should be vertically center aligned in the div, after the image. P.S. the image is 24x24px. However, it throws off the line-height to be about 12px too much (reducing the line-height to 12px does not solve it). Changing the image to be 12x12px though works and puts the text in the right spot. if the image is completely removed, the text is in the right spot. I guess my question is why is that doing what it is, and if/how I can fix it.

Thanks, sharf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `vertical-align:middle` to img

```
div > img
{
    float:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AFYfH/)

Comment: This fixes the text, but now my image goes from being aligned properly(in the middle) to being push down, so it actually hangs out of the div some.

Edit: giving it a vertical-align of top fixes it properly...seems strange to me.

Comment: Just `img { vertical-align: middle; }` seems to work ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZSxg/1/)). Why the `float: left` in addition?

Comment: infact vertical-align is not required. Float:left is enough. it seems like in @sharf comment it pushed down img a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding vertical-align to the img and experimenting with that to get it they way you want.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (but not always the best) solution is

```
img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

The image does not throw off line height; rather, it causes the height of the line box to become larger than `line-height`. The reason to this is that by default, an image is treated as if it were a letter, of the size specified by the image dimensions, sitting on text baseline. Thus, the image requires a height that is the height of the image itself plus the distance between text baseline and the bottom of the font.

In CSS terms, “sitting on text baseline” is caused by the default setting of `vertical-align: baseline`. You can override this in various ways, with different effects on the vertical placement, but beware that browsers have many bugs in the implementation of `vertical-align`, and the value of `bottom` is so simple that they probably get it right.